# SQL Query to select all rows from a table that do not exist in a different tables start and end time fields?

Tags: sql, datetime, presto

I have table1 who's rows I want to return that do not exist in that same ids start and end timestamp fields in table 2. I have the query below, but it is returning 0 rows. I cant see what I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1
WHERE table1.day = date '03-04-19'
  AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT NULL
     FROM table2
     WHERE table1.id = table2.id
       AND table1.timestamp >= table2.start_time
       AND table1.timestamp <= table2.end_time)
```

Comment: You can use a left outer join where table2.AnyCol equals null. Not sure in your query select null might be the issue?

Comment: Your query looks fine to me, except for the missing closing parenthesis. [It works fine in SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7a25e59c86f0667e1fcddac2e9c534d4). Does it return the rows withhout the `NOT EXISTS` condition? Maybe it's something about that `day = date '03-04-19'` condition?

Comment: Sorry the missing ) was a typo, fixed that. If I want to limit data return should I not filter for day? @MarcinJ

Comment: If you want to filter for a specific date then sure, you should probably filter, but maybe there's just no data for that day? Or the types don't match? Check if the query for just the date works fine, because that `NOT EXISTS` clause looks good. Best would be if you shared some of rows from `table1` and `table2` and told us what your expected output is.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your problem is simply your date format:

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1
WHERE table1.day = date '2019-04-03' AND
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM table2
                 WHERE table1.id = table2.id AND
                       table1.timestamp >= table2.start_time AND
                       table1.timestamp <= table2.end_time
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
  SELECT t1.*
    FROM table1 t1
    WHERE table1.day = date '03-04-19'
      AND NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT 1
         FROM table2 t2
         WHERE t1.id = table2.id
           AND t1.timestamp >= t2.start_time
           AND t1.timestamp <= t2.end_time)
```

Comment: I don't think any SQL implementation cares for what's returned from the `(NOT) EXISTS` clause, as long as it is. Neither [SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7a25e59c86f0667e1fcddac2e9c534d4), [MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2b94ffbb37703ae1d9f4881bc6d00e70) nor [Postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2b28f0b8d949adb1e6d49b1a79df5143) care for sure.

Answer (score -1):

I dont get why you are using >= and <=. But, you can try this:

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN
table2
ON
table1.id = table2.id
AND table1.timestamp >= table2.start_time
AND table1.timestamp <= table2.end_time
WHERE table1.date = CAST('03-04-19' as DATE)
AND table2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: They use >= and <= to check if a single date is between two other dates. And you query will produce duplicates from table1 when there exist multiple records in table2 with `id`, `start_time` and `end_time` matching records from `table1`, which is probably exactly what @Chris90 is trying to avoid by using `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: "do not exist in that same ids start and end timestamp fields in table 2". This statement conveyed me that the id, start_time, end_time fields combine to find the duplicates and that is why I used '=' instead of '<=' and '>='

Comment: Just to clarify, My query will produce records of table1, which is not found in table2 based on the join condition ( which can either be >= or =). I ensure this by checking "table2.id IS NULL".

Comment: @MarcinJ, I have edited the condition according to your suggestion and I think the query will now return records of table1 which were not in table2